unable to spawn process '/bin/sh' (Argument list too long)
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/husseinalatrach/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eClubDemo-gtdzjqqhbenxoidbeeiafpfwknho/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/eClubDemo/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/eClubDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/eClubDemo.build/Script-92234099A388A76FBDB092C1.sh (in target 'eClubDemo' from project 'eClubDemo')
    cd /Users/husseinalatrach/Desktop/e\&Eitsalat-Mobile/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/husseinalatrach/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eClubDemo-gtdzjqqhbenxoidbeeiafpfwknho/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/eClubDemo/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/eClubDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/eClubDemo.build/Script-92234099A388A76FBDB092C1.sh

I tried to clean project, then build its working, but if I need to archive, am facing this error: unable to spawn process '/bin/sh' (Argument list too long) (in target 'eClubDemo' from project 'eClubDemo').

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Inside Flutter Project,Navigate to :
MainProjectName => iOS => Flutter => Debug.xcconfig / Profile.xcconfig / Release.xcconfig;
Inside you will have duplicated lines remove all keep first 2 or 3
